# Where are widget screen positions (coordinates) stored?

Tags: macos, desktop, preferences, dashboard-widget, widgets

I keep a widget open on my desktop on my secondary monitor. Went away on vacation. No external monitor. The widget was "trapped" offscreen and active.

I tried looking in the preferences file for that widget but only the preferences for the widget were stored, not any meta-preferences ABOUT the widget, in this case its X and Y coordinates on the screen. I was hoping the pref file would have that information and I could just reset to 0,0.

It seems like it must be stored somewhere as it keeps its position every time I boot. I just don't know where it is or where to look.

Does anyone know where this information may be stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dashboard widget positions are stored in /Users/USERNAME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dashboard.plist (where USERNAME is your username on your Mac) and can be accessed by using Xcode to edit or possibly even TextEdit. When you open the file, you're looking for the values under 'layer-gadgets' and then 'Item X' (where X is the widget's position number in the Dashboard layout). Just locate and change 'pos-x' and 'pos-y' for your widget.

Good luck!

Comment: ...and there it is! Thank you so much. Problem solved. 

(ps: tried to upvote, but got the following message: "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.")

Comment: @verbatim - Great, thanks for letting me know it worked for you!

Comment: @verbatim - You're almost there! When you reach a reputation of 15 or higher, please come back and upvote/accept my answer. Thanks again!